# How do I control which tests to run in testng from ant?

Tags: ant, testng

In build.xml: the testng target has attributes like "testname" and "suitename". But these do not seem to activate or deactivate the corresponding tests or suites within the testng.xml file

Is this the right way to use these?

How can I control which tests or suites are run from within build.xml that references testng.xml?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I found this post to solve a similar problem:

http://www.nullin.com/2009/12/23/running-single-test-or-class-using-testng-and-ant/

As long as you can fit whichever parameters you want in the template (or make them replaceable), you can get most of the benefits from both approaches.

Answer (score 0):

You can't select a testng.xml *and* tell TestNG which tests to pick from that testng.xml. Use a different testng.xml file to do that.

The command line and ant/maven allow you to do some rudimentary selection too, but then you can't specify a testng.xml.

Comment: If you do that, won't you miss out on the great things the testng.xml has to offer, such as parameterized tests?

Comment: Yes, it's the downside of not using a testng.xml file. TestNG gives you a certain amount of control from the command line for convenience, but if you need to use all the features that TestNG has to offer, use a testng.xml.